# dropping categories with small sample using function in geom_violin

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like to request a way to drop the graph of the categories that display nothing in a violin plot (less than 3 obs?) ( BB and CCC in the figure). But keep all data for the whole sample sub plot. Is there a simpler way than filtering the dataframe and attaching a original copy (for the whole sample subplot).

```
# example df
library(ggplot2)
b<-abs(round(rnorm(8, sd=30)))
y<-runif(5)
pr<-y/sum(y)
names<-unlist(lapply(mapply(rep, LETTERS[1:5], 1:5), function (x) paste0(x, collapse = "") ) )
x <- sample(names, 8, replace=TRUE, prob=pr)
x
df<-data.frame(name=x,numbers=b)

violinplot_fun <- function(dataset, var, groupcol, adjust1, maxx) {
  ggplot(dataset)+
    geom_violin(aes_string(y = var, x = groupcol), scale = "width", 
                alpha = 0.4, adjust = adjust1) + 
    geom_violin(aes_(y = as.name(var), x = "Whole sample"), scale = "width", 
                alpha = .4, adjust = adjust1) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,ceiling(maxx)) , breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(15) ) + 
    coord_flip()
} 

violinplot_fun(df,"numbers", "name",0.5,100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit your data frame prior to calling it in the function using the `data.table` package, you can do it like this:

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt1 <- dt[, n := .N, by = name]
```

**EDIT** I changed your function slightly:

```
violinplot_fun <- function(dataset, dataset_orig, var, groupcol, adjust1, maxx) {
  ggplot(dataset)+
    geom_violin(aes_string(y = var, x = groupcol), scale = "width", 
                alpha = 0.4, adjust = adjust1) + 
    geom_violin(data = dataset_orig, aes_(y = as.name(var), x = "Whole sample"), 
                scale = "width", alpha = .4, adjust = adjust1) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,ceiling(maxx)) , breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(15) ) + 
    coord_flip()
} 

violinplot_fun(dt1[n >= 3,], dataset_orig = dt1, "numbers", "name",0.5,100)
```

gives you this:

[image]

Furthermore, if you know you won't be changing the threshold for individual acceptance (i.e., 3) then you could write your function like this so you only have to input one dataset argument:

```
violinplot_fun <- function(dataset, var, groupcol, adjust1, maxx) {
  ggplot(dataset[n >= 3]) +
    geom_violin(aes_string(y = var, x = groupcol), scale = "width", 
            alpha = 0.4, adjust = adjust1) + 
    geom_violin(data = dataset, aes_(y = as.name(var), x = "Whole sample"), scale = "width", 
            alpha = .4, adjust = adjust1) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,ceiling(maxx)) , breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(15) ) + 
    coord_flip()
}
```

Or, you could just set your threshold as an argument.

Comment: I edited it so that it filters out the categories with less than 3 observations only for the plot itself and the data table still has them in it

Comment: I think I understand your question better now. I made some slight adjustments to your function that will get you what you want